# When I try to input a string in C++, the program throws out a run time error

Tags: c++, string, scanf

I am trying to input a string in a C++ file by using `scanf()` (the compiler warns me to change `scanf()` to `scanf_s()`, so I changed it).

```
char string[3];
scanf_s("%s", string);
printf("%s", string);
```

I input "abc" in the console and press enter. Then the program will throw out the exception below

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF9C35B2079 (ucrtbased.dll) in
> Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location
> 0x0000008DD5D00000.

I can't figure out the error.

Comment: `scanf_s` requires the size of the string buffer to be the third paramater. Just as importantly, C-strings need to be NUL terminated. A three letter word requires four bytes to store.

Comment: Did you get any compiler warnings? You should treat them as errors.

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differenes or interactions between the two languages.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is more or less specific for the Microsoft C compiler which you are obviously using.

You probably want this:

```
...
char string[30];                       // you probably want more more room for your string
scanf_s("%s", string, sizeof(string)); // 3rd parameter must be the size of the buffer
printf("%s", string);
...
```

Read the documentation of [`scanf_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=msvc-170).

Another option is not to use `scanf_s` but just the standard `scanf`. Therefore you need to add `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` (for the MS compiler only) at the begin of your code:

Complete example:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  char string[30];
  scanf("%s", string);
  printf("%s", string);
}
```

Comment: `scanf_s` has made into C11 standard. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Comment: @pqnet I'm not sure if the Microsoft `scanf_s` is C11 standard compliant. But anyway many C environnments don't implement this anyway.

Comment: @pqnet although Microsoft's `scanf_s` does not follow the C11 specification